# Biblatex: Defining author = {} so that it leads to [Keine Autorenangabe] (engl. "no credits") in the output

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I am using **biblatex** for a paper in linguistics. A friend of mine used the entry "[ohne Autorenangabe]" (engl. something like "no credits") where the sources lacked of an author what holds for example for a number of newspaper articles. But he is working in Word. I was wondering whether it is possible to create some kind of command which produces the [ohne Autorenangabe] output.

In the biblatex document it could look like this

```
@book{example, 
author = {},
title = {Meaning of it}, 
year = 1998,
}
```

And the output look like this:

> [ohne Autorenangabe] (1998): Meaning of it.

So the question is, if it is possible to define `author = {}` in a way that it produces the [ohne Autorenangabe] (and maybe an English equivalent). The desired command would be suitable not only for the @book entry.

Notice: The entry `author = {Autorenangabe] [Kein}` doesnt lead to the desired result, because it will lead to an output including a comma: [Ohne, Autorenangabe].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`author = {[Kein~Autorenangabe]}`?

---

...or just define an [`@string` macro](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~collberg/Teaching/07.231/BibTeX/bibtex.html) with that in the BibTeX.

```
@string{unknown= {{[Kein~Autorenangabe]}}}

...

{ ...
   author = unknown
... }
```

Comment: I would be pleased with every kind of solution. As I am not the strongest man in the latex world, I dont know how to define a makro.

Comment: Added a macro for the bibtex file. `~` is just a non-breaking space.

Comment: I gave your solution a try in biblatex and it typeset something that looks like "Autorenangabe], [Kein". So this doesnt work properly

Comment: You would have to escape the first brackets:

    @string{unknown= {{[Kein~Autorenangabe]}}}