# Defining [keine Autorenangabe] so that it will be typeset in an author choosen place in the bibliography (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, sorting

badroit (supported by PLK) pointed out a way to create a makro to obtain an [ohne Autorenangabe] (english "no credits") output by using this (see [Biblatex: Defining author = {} so that it leads to [Keine Autorenangabe] (engl. "no credits") in the output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35890/biblatex-defining-author-so-that-it-leads-to-keine-autorenangabe-engl)):

```
@string{unknown= {{[Ohne~Autorenangabe]}}}
```

in combination with

```
@book{example, 
author = {},
title = {Meaning of it}, 
year = 1998,
}
```

Output: [ohne Autorenangabe] (1998): Meaning of it.

When I was using this, I realised that the entry is not in a good position in the bibliography. It is typeset between n and p entries following an alphabetical order.

My question: Is it possible to define the position of the entry? For example, that these entries occure in the beginning (or end) of the bibliography?

Answer (score 6):

With the version 1.7 of `biblatex` the new entry `xdata` was defined. The entry requires biber but allows you to set the `Ohne~Autorenangabe` with `sortname`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@XData{unknown-author,
author={{[Kein~Autorenangabe]}},
sortname={AAAAAA},
}

@book{example, 
xdata = {unknown-author},
title = {Meaning of it}, 
year = 1998,
}


@Book{companion,
  hyphenation     = {american},
  sorttitle   = {LaTeX Companion},
  author      = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  indextitle      = {LaTeX Companion, The},
  title       = {The LaTeX Companion},
  shorttitle      = {LaTeX Companion},
  edition     = {1},
  publisher   = {Addison-Wesley},
  location    = {Reading, Mass.},
  date        = {1994},
  pagetotal   = {528},
  annotation      = {A book with three authors. Note the formatting of the author list. By default,
            only the first name is reversed in the bibliography}
}
@Article{weinberg,
  author      = {Weinberg, Steven},
  title       = {A Model of Leptons},
  journaltitle    = {Phys.~Rev.~Lett.},
  volume      = {19},
  date        = {1967},
  pages       = {1264--1266}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```